# How can i pass multiple records to detail page in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

Hi i have master detail relationship in ReactJs, i need help passing multiple information from Master to detail page on button Click.

I have the the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-booth-o0488?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

in Master Page i have this link

```
<Link to={`${match.path}/${results.id}/empDetail`}>
                  {results.id}
                </Link>
```

Detail Page

```
function empDetail({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>ID {match.params.id}</h2>
      <h2>First Name: {match.params.id}</h2>
      <h2>Last Name: {match.params.id}</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

I want to pass `{results.ID}, {results.First_Name} and {results.Last Name}..` to `empDetail`

Answer (score 0):

You could send the result object as a prop to your child component rather than using URL params.

Something like this:

```
<Route path="/:outer/:id/empDetail" render={(props) => <empDetail details={result} {..props} />} />
```

Comment: thanks but doesnt work did you see my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-booth-o0488?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark?

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) takes to: object
An object that can have any of the following properties:

- **pathname**: A string representing the path to link to.
- **search**: A string representation of query parameters.
- **hash**: A hash to put in the URL, e.g. #a-hash.
- **state**: State to persist to the location.

state: does the trick for us i.e state: { pass: 'some data' }
So we can do something likes this

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/route', state: { id: results.ID,..other params} }}>My route</Link>
```

Then you can access the state object from within your component:

```
const {id} = props.location.state

console.log(id)
```

Your empDetail will look like this

```
function empDetail({ location }) {
const {state: { id, firstName, lastName }}= location
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>ID {match.params.id}</h2>
      <h2>First Name: {match.params.firstName}</h2>
      <h2>Last Name: {match.params.lastName}</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: i have more than 10 info or field do i have to list them all here `,..other params}`

Comment: Yes, you can pass any number of fields you want to pass here in the state object.

Comment: Akhil Thanks but it doesn't work, can you check my code https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-booth-o0488?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: tired it like this ` <Link to={{ pathname: '/route', state: { id: results.ID, results.Employee_Email }}}>My route</Link>`

Comment: How are you accessing it in your empDetail? As I'm able to log the props sent via link

Comment: something like this  `{match.params.Employee_Email }` then the field, did you have a chance to take a look at my code in the sandbox ?

Comment: it wont come in match object your function definition would be empDetail({ location }){
console.log(location.state. Employee_Email)
}